# How to delete files and folders from given path

Tags: c#

How I do delete the file and folder in `C:\Users\soft\Recent`?

When I tried this line

```
    string path="C:\Users\softw\Recent";
    foreach (var folder in Directory.GetDirectories(path))
       Directory.Delete(folder , true);

    foreach (var file in Directory.GetFiles(path))
     File.Delete(file);
```

I'm getting the following error

> Access to the path 'C:\Users\softw\Recent' is denied.

Kindly help me.

Comment: Not for this site, but check the permissions of the account you're using to execute the code. Check if the folder exists and the user has permissions on it.

Comment: Recent I thought was actually a bunch of registry settings not actual files

Comment: This is probably UAC kicking in... You're not supposed to edit files in that path. Either run your process elevated or store / edit / delete files in a proper location of your machine

Answer (score 0):

First you delete files in the root directory, then the directories recursively:

```
string path="C:\Users\softw\Recent"`;
System.IO.DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(path);

foreach (FileInfo file in di.GetFiles())
{
    file.Delete(); 
}
foreach (DirectoryInfo dir in di.GetDirectories())
{
    dir.Delete(true); 
}
```